# C# Connect to Siemens Hipath 3000

Tags: c#, tapi

I am needing to connect to a Siemens Hipath 3000 in order to do logging and pull reporting.
Has anyone used c# to do this, if you have done it in another language do you have any suggestions. I am currently looking at tapi in order to connect to it.

Thanks

Comment: Toy can do this without tapi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some documentation for Siemens HiPath / TAPI see http://wiki.siemens-enterprise.com/wiki/HiPath_3000_open_interfaces

Some starting points for TAPI via .NET:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/devangpro.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CShart_TAPI_3x.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734214.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am not familiar with what protocols the Siemens HiPath offers but it might offer a syslogd-integration and/or SNMP for logging purposes... some protocols (IIRC for example TAPI) need to be licensed additionally from Siemens...

Comment: Thanks seems tapi is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to configure the HiPath 3000 to send CDR via LAN to your specified IP address.
This configuration is easy via HiPath 3000 Manager E.

You simply write a TCP Listener to accept connection from the PBX and parse the incoming Call Detail Records (CDR).

Have done this successfully with Avaya, Panasonic and other PABX Products, including HiPath 3000 series.